# Opengl ES, issue while rendering close by objects

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working with opengl es on android. I have a 3d humanoid model on which i can put a hairstyle which is another 3d model. While rendering i could find that on the area where the two objects are very close/coincides (the head-hair region) the rendering is not proper, in fact i get different results on different mobile devices. I doubt it is z-fighting. Are there some solution for rendering close by objects properly with opengl es which will be consistent across all mobile devices. I have attached a snapshot for reference.

[image]

Here i have a face model on which i have placed a hair model but instead of showing the hair on top of the head, i get this kind of rendering.

Comment: It sounds exactly like z-fighting from the description. Why do you doubt it is z-fighting? Note that many older Android devices only support 16-bit depth buffers and dealing with that can be a significant challenge. Could you post a screenshot? I suppose the other likely candidate might be depth sorting with blending, hair models can often be challenging to alpha blend correctly because they often have crossed polygons with transparency.

Comment: I have attached an image showing the issue. Kindly go through.

Comment: Thank you. My suspicion there is that depth testing is not working at all, or is the wrong way around (so stuff that's further away is obscuring stuff that's closer) or that the back face culling is culling the wrong faces. Could you show what it looks like when there's no hair model and rendering is correct? If you render both the head and the hair model, but the hair model is off to one side, is rendering correct or broken? (it's possible that your hair model renderer is setting some render states which are breaking your scene)

Comment: Also, what are your near and far plane values for your camera, and what's the units? If your near plane is very near zero, or your far plane is huge, then you can get very bad depth precision. As a rough ballpark, a near plane of 2m and a far plane of 500m could be sensible for a 16-bit z buffer.

Comment: After testing on different devices I could find that this issue is specific to devices with Adreno series GPU,s only. On the other devices it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the float precision in the shader?

```
precision highp float;
```

for example. I've noticed different results on different handsets as well, and bad results if `highp` was not enabled on some.

Scaling the scene can also solve the issue.

Comment: I could find that this issue is specific to devices with Adreno series GPU,s only