# Opengl es rendering defects on places where models overlap

Tags: android, opengl-es

While using opengl es android, on certain mobile devices i am finding improper rendering on regions where models overlap/ where there are two models close by. I have attached some snapshots for reference. This works properly on one set of devices but on the other this issue persists.

[image: snapshot-1]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opengl ES, issue while rendering close by objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381785/opengl-es-issue-while-rendering-close-by-objects)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "[z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)" issues.
It's important to have

```
precision highp float;
```

set in the fragment shader. I've noticed it differs between handsets. If it persists, you can try to scale up the whole scene (say, 10 times).